# angualJS initial value shown in <input>

Tags: angularjs

I have this input form :

```
<input   title="Taper le nouveau nom" type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="file.name"/>
```

it works fine , it shows the name of the file ( a scope I have ) 
now I need to get the value typed by the user so I added ng-model="newname"

```
<input  ng-model="newname" title="Taper le nouveau nom" type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="file.name"/>
```

but this way, there's no initial values shown (file.name)
**How to fix this ?**

Comment: Try ng-model instead of ng-value

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do.  It looks like you are using the same input.  Is that right?
Whatever they type in the box that is what file.name will be set to.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model="file.newname"` says: the value in this input field is 2-way-bound to the attribute `newname` of the object `file`in the scope. Modifying the value in the input will modify the model, and modifying the model will modify the value in the input.

So simply make sure your controller initializes `$scope.file.newname` to the value you want the input to have initially:

```
$scope.file.newname = 'the new name';
```

Comment: thank you for answering. well I'm using  ng-repeat to get the list of my files and then for each file when I want to rename it , I want to see the oldname of the file in the input form  and then modify it . So I've soveld my problem by using `ng-init="newname=file.name" `

Comment: That is bad practice. Read the big red section at the top of https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit. Use JS code in your controller to initialize the newname of every file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-init to initialize the value

```
<div ng-init="file.newname=file.name">
  <input  ng-model="file.newname" ng-value="file.name"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is bad practice. The [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) warns about it: *The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.*

Comment: @JBNizet but OP said thst he/she is using ng-repeat and this case is appropriate for ng-init ..

Comment: No, not at all. Read the documentation again, especially the "as seen in the demo below". All the OP needs is a loop in the controller that initialize the newname attribute of each file. The OP doesn't need to have access to the $index of an outer loop from an inner loop.